# Different command based on if next line is empty

Tags: vim, viml

I'm trying to auto-add ; , or whatever is needed in the end of expression by a keystroke, and go to another line.

Basicly it'll be something like `inoremap <leader>; <C-o>A;`, but i want a little improvement. If next line is empty (or doesn't exist) i want it to do `<C-o>A;<cr>`, and if it isn't empty just `<C-o>A;<Down>`. In other words i need an idiomatic way to check if next line exist and if it's empty. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to the actual question:**

```
inoremap <expr> <leader>; getline(line(".")+1) =~ "^$" ? "\<C-o>A;\<CR>" : "\<C-o>A;\<Down>"
```

"Expression" mappings allow you to execute different macros depending on the result of one or more expressions. Here, we check if the line below is empty within a straightforward ternary operator.

Reference:

```
:help <expr>
:help getline()
:help line()
:help =~
```

---

**Original answer to the original question:**

```
inoremap <leader>; <C-o>A;^M
```

`^M` is a literal `<C-m>` (synonym of `<CR>`) that you obtain by pressing `<C-v>` then `<CR>`.

Comment: Sorry, my description was totally wrong (half it was deleted by mistake), you answer is correct to existed question, but i need something else. See edited question.